# Removing characters between brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, but I'm accessing that server via SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

I have a table called `Search` with a column `Body` of type `(nvarchar(Max), not null)`.

The data in this column is actually the body text of e-mails, and this column is keeping all HTML tags as part of the text.

For example the email body would show:

```
 Good morning
 This invoice has been assigned.
```

But when it's stored in the column called `Body`, it looks like this:

```
[size=14.0pt]Good morning
[/size][size=14.0pt]This invoice has been assigned.[/size]
```

I've having the following SQL to remove everything between "[" and "]" (including the brackets):

```
 SELECT 
     *,
     CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('[', Body) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(']', Body) > 0 
             AND CHARINDEX('[', Body) < CHARINDEX(']', Body) 
           THEN STUFF(Body, CHARINDEX('[', Body), (CHARINDEX(']', Body) - CHARINDEX('[', Body)) + 1, '')
           ELSE Body
     END AS Body1
FROM search
```

But all this does is removes the first set of Tags which now looks like this:

```
Good morning
[/size][size=14.0pt]This invoice has been assigned.[/size]
```

Can you help me with my SQL so that it will remove them all, so it will look like this:

```
Good Morning
This invoice has been assigned.
```

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using? e.g. MYSQL, MS SQL etc?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2, but I'm accessing that server via SQL Server Management Studio 2012. My apologies, I should had included that on my original post.

Comment: But that is NOT valid HTML. If it was actual HTML there are some tricks we can use. Since that doesn't seem to be the case I would suggest using CLR and regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a scalar function that removes square brackets and all the text contained between them:

```
create function [dbo].[fx_removetags] (@text nvarchar(max))
    returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
    declare @tag_start  int
    declare @tag_end    int
    declare @tag_length int
    set @tag_start = charindex('[', @text)
    set @tag_end = charindex(']', @text, charindex('[', @text))
    set @tag_length = (@tag_end - @tag_start) + 1
    while @tag_start > 0 and @tag_end > 0 and @tag_length > 0
        begin
            set @text = stuff(@text,@tag_start,@tag_length, '')
            set @tag_start = charindex('[',@text)
            set @tag_end = charindex(']',@text,charindex('[', @text))
            set @tag_length = (@tag_end - @tag_start) + 1
        end
    return ltrim(rtrim(@text))
end
```

Now you can invoke the function to get the text without brackets:

```
declare @test nvarchar(max)= ''
set @test = '[size=14.0pt]Good morning [/size][size=14.0pt]This invoice has been assigned.[/size] '

select [dbo].[fx_RemoveTags](@test)
```

Result:

[image]

In your specific case you use the function like this:

```
SELECT 
     *,
     [dbo].[fx_RemoveTags](@test) as Body1
FROM search
```

Comment: Andrea, thank you for your help.  I:n regards to the SQL statement, the part that says:

        set @test = '[size=14.0pt]Good morning [/size][size=14.0pt]This invoice has 
         been assigned.[/size] '

How do I reference the original field called "body".  This code works with the exact verbiage:

       [size=14.0pt]Good morning [/size][size=14.0pt]This invoice has been 
      assigned.[/size] ', 

but every entry into this field is different.

Comment: Did you test the function with different parameters? There's nothing in there that's use case specific....

Comment: Eric, thank you for the response I'm still learning SQL.  I ran it exactly like Andrea had posted and got the same exact result she did.  However, now I'm trying to understand how to Test this with column named "Body", where all the data is located.  I assume is has something to do with this line "set @test = '[size=14.0pt]Good morning [/size][size=14.0pt]This invoice has been assigned.[/size] '" but not sure how to change it to reference the "Body" Column in my Table named "Search".

Comment: This ought to work. `SELECT dbo.fx_RemoveTags(s.Body) FROM Search AS s;` Maybe try `SELECT TOP 10....` to start, just to validate the function.

Comment: @StephenMorrell Eric is right, you can use the function directly in your `select` statement replacing the `case ... when`. I updated my answer with an exmple

Comment: Thank you everyone this has helped very much.